# (Jailbroken) iOS 7 stock apps missing on springboard

Tags: iphone, applications, jailbreak, ssh, springboard

All apps from `private/var/stash/Applications.xxxxxx` are missing suddenly. I can't exactly say when that happened, don't think it was any specific `Cydia` tweak.
I still can `ssh` into my iPhone and see that the folder is still there, but the applications inside it won't show up on springboard. I already created a new symlink into root ("/") and I made `chmod 775` for the applications folder. I've run out of ideas and would like to avoid a full restore. What could be wrong and what can I do?

Comment: You really should just restore. That happened to me and that was all I could do.

Comment: Yes, that´s what I actually did now, because I need the iPhone in a working condition. But I´m pretty sure, there must be a way to fix that somehow.

Comment: I'm sure there is, but if it gets that messed up, I would argue that you should restore. When I had that happen, I couldn't access any stock iOS apps (they didn't show up), nor could I use the camera (even 3rd party camera apps didn't work).

Answer (score 1):

It's a Springboard glitch where the apps aren't shown.

- Install (or reinstall) a tweak in Cydia, then respring.
- Delete `/var/mobile/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installation.plist` then respring.
- Run `uicache` as mobile, then respring.

Comment: did both of it, but didn´t work...

Comment: I added a third potential solution