# Jailbroken iphone doesn't show stock apps or cydia itself

Tags: iphone

I recently jailbroke my phone and half of the stock apps are missing and cydia itself so it's hard for me to unjailbreak my phone as my computer is extremely slow

What do I do?

Comment: Maybe try jailbreaking again? If that doesn't work (which I suspect it won't), I think restoring your phone in iTunes is the only way to go. While you could probably fix things if you had a lot of knowledge of iOS and could install some tools, with cydia missing, you can't install the tools you'd need.

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120600/jailbroken-ios-7-stock-apps-missing-on-springboard?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Try a Hard Reset by holding down Home and Power Button Together. Screen will go black and when Apple Boot Logo appears release both the buttons. If you are lucky the you will get the missing apps